# Is there a way in HTML use layers and apply CSS file to a specific layer?

Tags: css, asp.net, html

Background:

There are different tools and components in the market that help developers/designers to create acceptable HTML interface without too much effort. The problem is that each of these tools have its own css settings and they don't all play well together. For example to user ASP.NET controls from one vendor and a special button set from another vendor, one has to do a lot of professional work to get the both working together on the same page due to css initialization and box model, etc.

My questions:

A - The concept of layers and canvas is already implemented in HTML5 but I see that it is mostly used for graphics (and game) development. Is it possible in HTML5 to create multiple layers where each layer could them be associated with a unique set (1 or more) css files, hence preventing application of css settings to another layer? This way one could group visual components to multiple layers and use them without problems.

My understanding is that this is not possible.

B - Do you see a better approach to solve the problem of mixing css files from different components as described in the background above?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some examples of conflicting CSS on this case?

Comment: @renanlf, while I don't want to name 3rd party names, take Bootstrap framework and some of the leading vendors of UI controls for ASP.NET. This is also the case if you wanted to use WYSIWYG design tool with any other UI control library.

Comment: I think your best bet is to try and _"scope"_ the CSS styles. If everything from _Package A_ had a leading `.pa` class and everything from _Package B_ had a leading `.pb` class then you would add `.pa` or `.pb` to the elements to signify which package's CSS to use, `<div class="pa"><div class="other"></div></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

A - You're right. This isn't possible!

B - You can wrap the VendorA component in a div with some class `vendor-a` and then prefix all CSS classes on this VendorA .css file with the `.vendor-a class`.

Example:
Supose you have on vendorA.css a style for buttons that is conflicting:

```
button { ... }
```

You would have to prefix it:

```
.vendor-a button { ... }
```

And on your HTML you will have to wrap the component in a:

```
<div class="vendor-a">
    <!-- Vendor A component goes inside -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. for the suggestion. I am sorry that the layered approach won't work. The other thing that will affect the result is the CSS Rest used and the box model...Not sure why the W3C did not sort all this in the first place!